# Java doesn't box and convert primitive types at the same time

Tags: java, javac, primitive-types, autoboxing, syntactic-sugar

I know that java(c?) can box and unbox types and convert between primitive types when necessary, but why does it not want to do that both at the same time.

For example if I were to do this:

```
ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
bytes.add(8);
```

Javac will panic and tell me `Collection.add(Byte)` is not applicable, but were I to use `ArrayList<Integer>` instead it would not be a problem.
If I would do `byte aByte = 8; bytes.add(aByte);` it would also compile fine.

Why is this, is there a good reason for this?

Comment: That's because, you want to cast a literal int to byte, int = 4 bytes, while byte is one byte, so you are going down, here Java will not decide at your place, for that you need an EXPLICIT CAST because maybe you will lose some data, if you want to go up (in bytes number), for ex : from int to double, Java will do an IMPLECIT CAST for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this happen is because if you do `bytes.add(8)`, 8 is handled as an int. So the following error is thrown:

> The method add(Byte) in the type ArrayList < Byte> is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int)

If you want to add 8 directly to your ArrayList you have to cast 8 to a byte

```
bytes.add((byte)8);
```

It is not possible to handle 8 as a `byte` when necessary and in other cases as an `int`.

Think of the following example:

```
private static void test() {
  Object o = 8;
}
```

Now there wouldn't be specified if you want 8 as an `byte` or an `int`.
So numbers are handled always as ints and no as bytes. So the JVM can box the 8 to the correct wrapper class. `o.getClass()` is `java.lang.Integer` in this example.

The same thing is with decimals,e.g. `2.3` is defined as a double if you want `2.3` as an float you have to write `2.3f`.

Comment: Man Dimi you were faster. Just wanted to write exactly that. :P 
Take my upvote

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I said, what I asked was why doesn't java handle 8 as a byte?

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope this will make it a little clearer why numbers must be handled always as the same type @S.Klumpers

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it @Vancold.at